# Calculate derivative of function at point in Scala Breeze

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism, breeze, tensor

I am trying to calculate the numeric approximation of the derivative of a given function at a point. It should be very straightforward, i.e., $f'(a) = \lim\limits_{\Delta\to 0} \frac{f(a+\Delta) - f(a-\Delta)}{2\Delta}$.

I have (literally) just started using Breeze yesterday. I wanted it to work on both `DenseVector` and `DenseMatrix` (not sure why there must be both in Breeze, but anyway) so I thought I should use `Tensor`. I thought I could do it with something like this:

```scala
def deriv[K,Double](f: UFunc, a: Tensor[K,Double]): Tensor[K,Double] = {
    val delta = 0.0001d
    (f(a + delta) - f(a - delta)) / (2*delta)
}
```

But I got the following errors:

```
cmd36.sc:5: could not find implicit value for parameter op: breeze.linalg.operators.OpAdd.Impl2[breeze.linalg.Tensor[K,Double],Double,That]
    (f(a + delta) - f(a - delta)) / (2*delta)
         ^
cmd36.sc:5: could not find implicit value for parameter op: breeze.linalg.operators.OpSub.Impl2[breeze.linalg.Tensor[K,Double],Double,That]
    (f(a + delta) - f(a - delta)) / (2*delta)
                        ^
Compilation Failed
```

I tried to write specific versions for `DenseVector` and for `DenseMatrix` with no success either. But when I change the time of function I am using AND the type of parameter, then I get what I was expecting.

```scala
def deriv(f: DenseVector[Double] => DenseVector[Double], a: DenseVector[Double]): DenseVector[Double] = {
    val delta = 0.001d
    (f(a + delta) - f(a - delta)) / (2.0*delta)
}

def deriv(f: DenseMatrix[Double] => DenseMatrix[Double], a: DenseMatrix[Double]): DenseMatrix[Double] = {
    val delta = 0.001d
    (f(a + delta) - f(a - delta)) / (2.0*delta)
}
```

The code above compiles and works as intended. But I have to write the exact same code twice.

Can anyone:

(a) Explain why my first attempt (`UFunc`+`Tensor`) does not work?
(b) Show how this (`deriv`) could be achieved in a more elegant (polymorphic) way without too much overhead?

Thanks.